# ¿Como selecciono los registros de hace 6 horas?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en donde guardo usuarios y la columna fecha_registro es del tipo DATETIME, lo que necesito es seleccionar los registros de entre hace 6 y 7 horas. Como puedo hacer esto?. Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido seas, te comento que por favor leas [ask], para que por favor edites y nos muestres que has intentado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es una query que tienes que lanzar en muchas ocasiones y no quieres tener que poner cada vez que haces esa query la fecha:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha_registro BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR);
```

Con NOW() obtenemos la fecha y hora del momento de lanzar la query.
Mediante DATE_SUB y los INTERVAL restamos las horas requeridas a la fecha.
Y finalmente con BETWEEN indicamos a mysql el rango.

Answer (score 2):

Deberías usar **BETWEEN** en tu clausula where aunque podrias ver mas a fondo en la documentación.

```
SELECT dato_que_quieres_mostrar
WHERE fecha_registro BETWEEN ('2018-01-10','06:30:00') AND ('2018-01-10','12:30:00');
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html